# Play framework app in heroku - i18n does not work

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework, internationalization

I deployed my playframework app to Heroku but the internationalization is not working.

I am using play 2.4 and I followed these tutorials:

[ScalaI18N](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaI18N)

[Deploying to heroku](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ProductionHeroku)

My application.conf:

```
# The application languages
# ~~~~~
play.i18n.langs = [ "en", "es", "pt-BR"]
```

I created the messages.en, messages.es and messages.pt-BR.

When I test it local, is in portuguese.

When I deploy to heroku it is in English.

What am I missing? Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can try adding the default `conf/messages` file. Anyway, the language applied to messages depends on the `Accept-Language` header sent by the browser/client, the environment has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Are your messages.X files checked into Git? you can verify with `git ls-files`

Comment: Yes, my messages files are checked in git.